# Python Nested Loop Problems With Validation

Tags: python

I'm creating a work log where a user can input a task or lookup a task by dates.

When looking up task by date, the user is presented with a list of dates.  The user can then select from the list by entering a number.  The list of tasks should then display for that specific date.

I'm just having a problem if the user enters a number not in the list of dates. You can see else statement at the end of method which is commented out---which had been causing a few issues.  Everything works fine otherwise.  So question--how do i provide error message if input from user is not in index list without printing out the message every time it loops through the list?

```
def search_by_date(self):
    for i, d in enumerate(self.tasklist.dates()):
        enum_list = [(i+1,d) for i,d in enumerate(self.tasklist.dates())]
        print(i+1, ':', d)
    while True:
        datereq = input("Select Number To See Tasks For A Date: ").strip()
        try:
            datereq = int(datereq)

        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Entry")
            continue

        else:
            for i, d in enum_list:
                for task in self.tasklist.task_list:
                    if datereq == i:
                        if task.date == d:
                            print("Date :", task.date,
                                  " Task:", task.task,
                                  " Minutes:", task.minutes,
                                  " Notes: ", task.notes
                                  )
                            continue

                    #else:
                        #print("Invalid Entry. Please try again")
                        #continue
```

Comment: `continue` should probably be `break`. The `continue` statement has no effect here, it doesn't skip anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
def search_by_date(self):
    for i, d in enumerate(self.tasklist.dates()):
        enum_list = [(i+1,d) for i,d in enumerate(self.tasklist.dates())]
        print(i+1, ':', d)
    while True:
        datereq = input("Select Number To See Tasks For A Date: ").strip()
        try:
            datereq = int(datereq)

        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Entry")
            continue

        else:
            found = False
            for i, d in enum_list:
                for task in self.tasklist.task_list:
                    if datereq == i and task.date == d:
                        found = True
                        print("Date :", task.date,
                              " Task:", task.task,
                              " Minutes:", task.minutes,
                              " Notes: ", task.notes
                              )
            if not found:
                print("Invalid Entry. Please try again")
```

Comment: that's strange: it will print "invalid entry" whatever the result is.

Comment: Yes, without his data objects I can't actually run the code :) One sec as I fix

Comment: Hi Julien--yes when i try this it prints all the right results, but prints the Invalid Entry line at the end.  For an actual invalid entry it is working correctly.  Hmm..

Comment: I thought of an `else` statement matching the for loop but there are 2 for loops. you'll have to go with a flag telling that it's found.

Comment: nitpick: don't use `== True` or `!= True`. Just use `if found:` and `if not found`

Comment: only problem i'm having with this is that it is only printing one of the tasks.  so if there are say three tasks for a specific date, it is only printing one instead of all three.

Comment: AH YES that is it!  Thank you @Julien!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: It would probably be helpful to include, as a general rule: 1. what the problem was; 2. what you've changed; and 3. how 2 fixes 1.